# Pick date from three selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I would like to write a date picking mechanism like [this](http://www.nickabusey.com/jquery-date-select-boxes-plugin/).

Has anyone used this plugin?

I would like to know if I have to populate my 3 selects ( birthDay, birthMonth and birthYear) with days, months and years values? If so, what is a best way to do that?

Comment: Are you just asking how to use the plugin that you linked to?  Did you read the instructions on the site?

Comment: No,more important part is the second one. I need to populate 3 selects with date values, and I would like to know what is a best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the [jQuery datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Admittedly, it doesn't use selects as interface elements, but it has a very polished interface that's (arguably) even easier to use, and you can easily parse the month, day and year out of the chosen value and use them to populate hidden inputs if your server-side code expects the three values separately.

Comment: I've found this to be a better user experience, and also easier programmatically to work with.

Comment: I might be able to help more if I knew why. You have goals/restraints that I can't see.